# Django rejects certain Slug URLs but accepts others

Tags: python, django, slug

I have a Django project I am working on, I have just realised that certain URLs are rejected by the server with the error:

> **NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'mapView' with arguments '(u'intranet.hieta.biz',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'QMSv2/(?P[\w-]+)/$']**

The weird thing I dont get about this that half of the pages work and are reachable but the others arent. They all share the same format, database, view, url, template.. I cannot spot a difference. This is the url it is trying to match it to:

**`url(r'^(?P[\w-]+)/$', views.mapView, name="mapView")`**

If anyone has any idea of what might cause Django to reject certain slugs and not others then please let me know any help is immensely appreciated!!

**Note**: All pages are rendered with the same template, url and view. The slugs are all in the same database and the slugs themselves are all generated from the same function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your group `[\w-]+` matches A-Z, a-z, 0-9, underscores and hyphens, but does not match periods `.`. You should change it to:

```
[\w.-]+
```

Comment: thank you a ton! Any idea why every URL uses the same name yet only some were reject by the regex?

Comment: I would expect your old url to work for the slug `intranet` but not `intranet.hieta.biz` because it contains a period.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I was asking why it would ACCEPT half of the slugs (all using the same url just a different /my-slug/) and REJECT the others. I understand the '.' causing the rejection but why can it accept the others?

Comment: You're right, I'm afraid I don't understand your question. Which slugs are rejected that do not contain `.`?

Comment: The domain stays consistent so it will always be intranet.hieta.biz/my-slug/ examples of rejected slugs are: post-flm, document-numbering, non-conforming-material. Examples of accepted ones: overall-qms, continuous -improvement, company-policies

Comment: The error message `with arguments '(u'intranet.hieta.biz',)'` shows that something is trying to use `'intranet.hieta.biz'` *as the slug*. Your question doesn't have enough information to show where this is happening. You could have a slug `'intranet.hieta.biz'` in your database, or perhaps the problem is in a view where you call `reverse` or template where you use the `url` tag.